# Sparql Query to retrieve all the properties and classes belong to specific class

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, semantic-web

I have ontology URI and I need to know all the properties and classes belongs to this ontology.
the URI of the ontology Prefix Names: http://data.Ordanancesurvery.cor.uk/ontology/OpenName#.
It is hosted by ordnance survey and The API is:
https://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/explorer/sparql
I need Sparql query which can retrieve all the classes and properties from the ontology.

---

```
 PREFIX Names: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/OpenNames/> 
 PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX owl:<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

      SELECT  ?s ?p ?o

       WHERE {
        ?s ?p ?o

 Filter (regex (?o,"OpenNames")) 

  }
```

---

I am trying to retrieve all the classes and properties, belong to the ontology OpenNames under the uri :  http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/OpenNames/

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow works better if you show (1) small sample of data (2) attempts so far to query it.

Comment: I need to retrieve all the classes and properties defined under the http://data.Ordanancesurvery.cor.uk/ontology/OpenName.

Comment: PREFIX Names: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/OpenNames/> 
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl:<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT  ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o

     Filter (regex (?o,"OpenNames")) 
}

Comment: why aren't you using a triple pattern to get the classes?

Comment: What do u mean please can you specify ?

Answer (score 1):

URIs are not strings. Conversion is not automatic. Use `str(?o)`

`regex (str(?o),"OpenNames")` or `CONTAINS(str(?o),"OpenNames")`

Better is

`STRSTARTS(str(?o), str(Names:))`

Prefixes are expanded during parsing so

```
str(Names:)
```

is the same as writing

```
str(<http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/OpenNames/>)
```

then `STRSTARTS` does a leading string test.